# How can you tell distances/duration in Paths of the soul?

Tags: realism, paths-of-the-soul

In *[Paths of the Soul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paths_of_the_Soul)*, a group of Tibetan shepherd-folk make a pilgrimage to Lhasa. Occasionally we see milestones on the road they follow, with some kind of distance listed. However, it's not clear what's the point on that road they need to get to; and descriptions of the movie list the distance they need to cover at 1200 Km - a third or so of the listed distance. It's also difficult to tell how much they cover in a day and how many days pass between scenes.

Are we supposed not to know? Or is the case that the filmmaker assumes some kind of geographical knowledge that Tibetans/Western-Chinese would have?